# Abstract class and unique pointer

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, c++14, abstract-class

I have the following error in my code:

`error: allocating an object of abstract class type 'Material'`

I don't know how to handle this case.

I'm aware that `std::make_unique` performs an allocation, so it can't allocate the object of type `Material`, but I don't know how to correct it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Material
{
  Material() = default;
  virtual int get_color() const = 0;
};

struct Basic : public Material
{
  Basic() = default;
  virtual int get_color() const override
  {
    return 1;
  }
};

struct Mix : public Material
{
  Mix(const Material& mat1, const Material& mat2)
    : mat1_(std::make_unique<Material>(mat1))
    , mat2_(std::make_unique<Material>(mat2))
  {}

  virtual int get_color() const override
  {
    return mat1_->get_color() + mat2_->get_color();
  }     
private:
  std::unique_ptr<Material> mat1_;
  std::unique_ptr<Material> mat2_;
};

int main()
{
  auto mix = Mix(Basic(), Basic());
  std::cout << mix.get_color() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Is it correct that in `Mix`'s constructor you want to dynamically allocate a storage for two objects (pointed to by `unique_ptr`s) and copy constructor's arguments there?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This call:

```
std::make_unique<Material>(mat1)
```

tries to create an instance of class `Material`, it is irrelevant what type `mat1` has. You seem to need method `clone()` in your class:

```
class Material {
...
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Material> clone() const = 0;
};
```

then `Mix` ctor would be:

```
Mix(const Material& mat1, const Material& mat2)
    : mat1_(mat1.clone())
    , mat2_(mat2.clone())
  {}
```

and you need to implement `clone()` in every derived class:

```
struct Basic : public Material
{
  Basic() = default;

  virtual std::unique_ptr<Material> clone() const override
  {
      return std::make_unique<Basic>( *this ); 
  }

  virtual int get_color() const override
  {
    return 1;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is because `Mix` tries to create an object of the abstract class `Material`:

```
: mat1_(std::make_unique<Material>(mat1))
```

Ideally, based on the signature

```
Mix(const Material& mat1, const Material& mat2)
```

`Mix` should be able to just operate on any type of `Material` passed to it.

The fact that `Mix` is passed with abstract class reference is good. But the fact that `Mix` is trying to create objects of derived class is unusual. What if there were other derived classes?

I would design slightly differently such that `Mix` is *not* the owner of the constituents; they are created and owned by something outside, `Mix` just mixes what is passed to it.

```
struct Mix : public Material
{
  Mix(const Material& mat1, const Material& mat2)
    : mat1_{mat1}, mat2_{mat2}
  {}

  virtual int get_color() const override
  {
    return mat1_.get_color() + mat2_.get_color();
  }     
private:
  Material const& mat1_;
  Material const& mat2_;
};

int main()
{
  std::unique_ptr<Material> mat1 = std::make_unique<Basic>();
  std::unique_ptr<Material> mat2 = std::make_unique<Basic>();

  auto mix = Mix(*(mat1.get()), *(mat2.get()));
  std::cout << mix.get_color() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: This can be reasonable, but it creates the requirement that a caller must ensure the lifetime of the two Material objects exceeds that of the the Mix object. Compilers and other tooling tend not to be able to help check such requirements. Such requirements can be problematic under maintenance, unless e.g. a single object has the responsibility of maintaining that coordination. Sometimes those requirements are necessary if other objects must control the lifetime. Sometimes Mix and MixMaterialHolder would be too many types, and adding ownership responsibilities to Mix would be better.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a templated constructor to arrange for constructing the right types without needing a clone method:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Material {
    Material() = default;
    virtual int get_color() const = 0;
};

struct Basic : Material {
    Basic() = default;
    int get_color() const override {
        return 1;
    }
};

struct Mix : Material {
    template<typename M1, typename M2>
    Mix(const M1& mat1, const M2& mat2)
        : mat1_{std::make_unique<M1>(std::move(mat1))}
        , mat2_{std::make_unique<M2>(std::move(mat2))}
    {} 

    int get_color() const override {
        return mat1_->get_color() + mat2_->get_color();
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Material> mat1_;
    std::unique_ptr<Material> mat2_;
};

int main() {
    auto mix = Mix(Basic(), Basic());
    std::cout << mix.get_color() << '\n';
}
```

Note that this works only if you send instance of a material with a known type.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/236974/ contains the proper solution.
The `make_shared` and `make_unique` should be of the specific type; you can then without issues store this in a `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` of the abstract type.

Comment: `make_shared` and `make_unique` and `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` respectively.
Lol best and most efficient answer