# Abstract Class in std::unique_ptr as a Return from Function not Working

Tags: c++, polymorphism, std, subclass, unique-ptr

```
class Base{
public:
    virtual std::string typeName() = 0;
    virtual ~Base() = 0;
};
Base::~Base(){}

class D1 : public Base{
public:
    std::string typeName();
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> children;
    ~D1(){};
};
class D2 : public Base{
public:
    std::string typeName();
    std::unique_ptr<Base> child;
    ~D2(){};
};
std::string D1::typeName(){
    return "class D1";
}
std::string D2::typeName(){
    return "class D2";   
}

class Program{
public:
   std::unique_ptr<Base> D1Generic();
   std::unique_ptr<Base> D2Generic();
};
std::unique_ptr<Base> Program::D1Generic(){
    return std::make_unique<Base>(D1{});
}
std::unique_ptr<Base> Program::D2Generic(){
    return std::make_unique<Base>(D2{});
}
```

This code is just a simplified version that replicates the problem I'm facing.
My intention with this design is to create a visitor pattern on a tree, and turn that into another tree.

I've narrowed down the immediate problem to the `D1Generic` and `D2Generic` functions. My intention here was to create an expandable interface that allows multiple subclasses of `Base` to fit as a unique pointer variable polymorphically.

I got these errors:

```
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.5.0/../../../../include/c++/7.5.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:821:34: error: 
      allocating an object of abstract class type 'Base'
    { return unique_ptr<_Tp>(new _Tp(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)); }
                                 ^
main.cpp:38:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::make_unique<Base, D1>' requested here
    return std::make_unique<Base>(D1{});
                ^
main.cpp:8:25: note: unimplemented pure virtual method 'typeName' in 'Base'
    virtual std::string typeName() = 0;
                        ^
main.cpp:9:13: note: unimplemented pure virtual method '~Base' in 'Base'
    virtual ~Base() = 0;
            ^
In file included from main.cpp:4:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.5.0/../../../../include/c++/7.5.0/memory:80:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.5.0/../../../../include/c++/7.5.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:821:34: error: 
      allocating an object of abstract class type 'Base'
    { return unique_ptr<_Tp>(new _Tp(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)); }
                                 ^
main.cpp:41:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::make_unique<Base, D2>' requested here
    return std::make_unique<Base>(D2{});
                ^
2 errors generated.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The underlying issue is explored in [Abstract class and unique pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44413478/abstract-class-and-unique-pointer), but solutions details are different.*

A call to `std::make_unique<T>` dynamically allocates an object of type `T`. The parameters do not affect what is created, only how it is initialized. When you provide an object of type `D1` to initialize a dynamically-allocated object of type `Base`, a reference to the `D1` object is cast to a reference to its `Base` sub-object, and the new object is copy-constructed from that.

What you (presumably) want to do is dynamically allocate an object of type `D1`, then cast its address to a pointer-to-`Base`. That is, cast *after* construction.

```
return std::make_unique<D1>();
```

This dynamically allocates an object of type `D1`, creating a `unique_ptr` to the new object. This smart pointer is returned via move semantics. That means the returned object (declared as `unique_ptr<Base>`) is move-constructed from the `unique_ptr<D1>` returned by `make_unique`. Fortunately, this is allowed!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> Program::D1Generic() {
    return (std::unique_ptr<Base>)new D1();
}
std::unique_ptr<Base> Program::D2Generic() {
    return (std::unique_ptr<Base>)new D2();
}
```