# call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor while using unique_ptr c++ 17

Tags: c++, c++17

I have following setup:

```
class A {
public:
    constexpr A() = default;
    virtual ~A() = default;

    virtual void print() const noexcept = 0;
    virtual std::unique_ptr<A> clone() const noexcept = 0;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    constexpr B() {};
    B(const A& a1, const A& a2) : ptr1(a1.clone()), ptr2(a2.clone()) {}

    virtual ~B() = default;

    virtual void print() const noexcept override {
        std::cout << "In B\n";
    }

    void printPtrs() const noexcept {
        ptr1->print();
        ptr2->print();
    }

    virtual std::unique_ptr<A> clone() const noexcept override {
        return std::make_unique<B>(*this);
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<A> ptr1;
    std::unique_ptr<A> ptr2;
};

class C : public A {
public:
    constexpr C() = default;
    virtual ~C() = default;

    virtual void print() const noexcept override {
        std::cout << "In C\n";
    }

    virtual std::unique_ptr<A> clone() const noexcept override {
        return std::make_unique<C>(*this);
    }
};

===== MAIN =============
#include "MyClass.h"

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    C c;
    B b;
    B B_container(b, c);
    B_container.printPtrs();

    return 0;
}
```

I used the 'clone()' method taking the suggestion from this issue: [Abstract class and unique pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44413478/abstract-class-and-unique-pointer)

I am getting this error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'B'
I am really struggling with this, I don't understand why this copy ctor being called here? Any work around?

Comment: "why this copy ctor being called here?" What is your working plan for `clone`? How is it supposed to function if not by making a copy?

Comment: You've painted yourself into a corner.  You can't copy `B because `std::unique_ptr` has a deleted copy constructor (for obvious reasons), which in turns means that `B` isn't copiable either.  But since neither class `A` nor class `B` contain any actual data members, this is all a bit meaningless anyway.  What we need here is a more realistic example.  What you've posted so far is all very circular.

Answer (score 3):

`B::clone` attempts to copy a `B` object, but `B` is non-copyable due to its `std::unique_ptr` members.

Since you have a constructor that accepts two references to `A` objects and clones them, you could use that instead:

```
virtual std::unique_ptr<A> clone() const noexcept override {
    return std::make_unique<B>(*ptr1, *ptr2);
}
```

This will create a new `B` object that holds pointers to copies of the `A` objects pointed to by `this` object's `unique_ptr` members instead of attempting to copy the `unique_ptr`s themselves, which you cannot do.

Comment: Note that this wil fail (cause undefined behavior and probably crash) if either of ptr1 or ptr2 are nullptr, as will be the case if `this` was constructed by the default ctor (`b` in `main`).  You need to test ptr1/ptr2 and only attempt to call clone() if they are valid.  This can be done much more cleanly by writing a B ctor that takes two A * instead of two A & and tests for nullptr

Comment: `C` suffers the same injury as `B`. But the naming shows the bigger problem: how can a none-copyable object be clonable? A proper copy-ctor is best direction.